# Confusion in understanding a simple convex optimization problem's solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am learning optimization through a course on Youtube.  I have one confusion in solving the following problem. As per my understanding, the objective function is not convex. The problem is a constraint optimization problem.

Please see the following problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{3}{2} y^2 + 2x\\ \text{subject to} & x - y = 0\end{array}$$

As per my understanding, the given function should not be a convex function because

1. When I draw the graph, I saw that the line joining the two points on the convex set sometimes lies above, while other times lie below the graph itself. (See the attached figure I plotted in Python).
2. When I found the eigenvalue for the function using the Hessian matrix, it came out to be negative. Again, as per my knowledge about convex programming, a convex function has its eigenvalue as positive.

It can be seen from the graph clearly, that the point where gradient comes out to be zero is a saddle point and neither local minima, nor maxima.

Still, the instructor solved this problem as a convex problem using Lagrange function. Is there anything that I am missing or did the instructor made a mistake (by the way, the instructor taught very well generally)

[image: 3D Graphical representation of the function f(x,y)]

[image: Snapshot from the course]

Comment: The problem as stated does not have a solution. Why do you expect the cost to be convex?

Comment: sorry, my bad. Please check the correction

Comment: The cost can be made arbitrarily small, so there is no $\min$ as such.

Comment: I don't see how we can be responsive to "Is there anything that I am missing or did the instructor made a mistake [...]?" without your presentation of the instructor's work or your proper citation of the source.

Comment: I can only find this way to share the course material that I post the snapshot from the course. Please find in the edit version. After this snapshot-ed time, the instructor went on to find the sufficient condition to prove that  (1,1) is local maxima, and (2,2) is local minima.

Comment: Can I at least know that my approach, towards solving the problem and coming to conclusion that the given problem is a non-convex function, is right?  I'll appreciate that.

Comment: If you substitute $y=x$ and solve for $x$ you can see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F3%29x%5E3++-+%283%2F2%29x%5E2+%2B+2x that the values you have obtained are just the local min and maximum value. If the objective function was convex then your method looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, @AsAnExerciseProve (+1). I saw your illustrations. It makes sense now. It made me realize that when we are using Lagrange multipliers, then we do not need to do the Convexitiy test. Am I right in making this assumption? With my research over the topic, I think Lagrange multipliers and Lagrangian functions can be used for both convex and non-convex functions.

Comment: When you set the gradient to $0$ you are just finding a local minimum, local maximum, or saddle point of a function. If the function is convex then we know that this point corresponds to a global minimum. This is the reason why people are interested in convex functions. If you don't check convexity then you really aren't solving an optimization problem anymore. For example, minimize $x^3$. the gradient is $0$ and $x=0$. This point is not a local minimum or maximum.

Comment: But that was my point in the question. The convexity test shows that this problem is not a convex problem :(